# How to read and write files using printf and scanf in C?

Tags: c, file, printf, scanf

A little backstory: Some years ago, I was on a algorithm contest. By that time, I was learning C, and I didn't know how to write or read files using the normal methods.

In order to no get confused by new methods and syntax, a C wizard, told me to add a couple of lines after the includes, and presto, any program that printed to the screen using printf and getting the input from the keyboard using scanf, would read and write to separate files declared in those lines.

Those codes only ran in Windows, so I don't know if it was portable. I don't remember adding includes besides stdio.h, conio.h and maybe, stdlib.h. I've searched on the net how to do it, but with no results. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: google for file I/O using C.

Comment: Probably calling freopen on stdin and stdout.  I'll try to make an example tonight.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `stdio.h`? An easy way to remember that is by remembering that it's an acronym for "standard input/output". `conio.h` is non-portable and irrelevant, and rarely useful compared to the standard, portable equivalent `stdio.h`.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Apologies for the typo in the library. When I learned C my English was worse than now (!) and I remember stdio.h by the word study and not the acronym, since is phonetically equal to study in spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have three options.

### **Option I**

Redirect `stdin`/`stdout` (those are the streams `scanf` reads from and `printf` writes to) in the console, when you start your program. On both Windows and Linux, this can be done like so:

- `< in.txt` - redirects all reads from `stdin` to `in.txt`
- `> out.txt` - redirects all writes to `stdout` to `out.txt`

You can combine these. For example, to have your program read from `in.txt` and write to `out.txt`, do this in the terminal (command line):
`myprogram < in.txt > out.txt`

### Option 2

Again, you can redirect the standard streams, this time in your code, using `freopen`. For example:

```
freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);
freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
```

The result will be exactly the same as above.

### Option 3

Use C's file I/O: first `fopen`, then `fscanf` and `fprintf`:

```
FILE* fIn, fOut;
fIn = fopen("in.txt", "r");
fOut = fopen("out.txt", "w");
// Here you should check if any of them returned NULL and act accordingly
```

You can then read and write like so:

```
fscanf(fIn, "%d %d", &x, &y);
fprintf(fOut, "Some result: %d\n", result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, option 2 is exactly what I used mindlessly time ago.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct s
{
char name[50];
int height;
};
int main(){
    struct s a[5],b[5];   
    FILE *fptr;
    int i;
    fptr=fopen("file.txt","wb");
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter name: ");
        gets(a[i].name);
        printf("Enter height: "); 
        scanf("%d",&a[i].height); 
    }
    fwrite(a,sizeof(a),1,fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    fptr=fopen("file.txt","rb");
    fread(b,sizeof(b),1,fptr);
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\nHeight: %d",b[i].name,b[i].height);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```